# Indexeddb - can I start coding for it today?

Tags: firefox, html, google-chrome

I have the latest version of Firefox (4 beta) and Chrome.  I would like to start hacking up some ideas for what I could do with indexedDb.  So far, it looks like it is not yet available in either browser.

Any ideas on when it will be available?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in Firefox 4 Beta 1, but it's `moz_indexedDB`, not `indexedDB` (specification is not yet in candidate recommendation)

Comment: Ah, ok, then that is what I will code to.  Thanks much, now if I can only get firebug in there, I'll be golden.

Comment: On Firefox 6.x, it doesn't appear to be "moz_indexedDB"

Comment: It was renamed to `mozIndexedDB` AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

It's in Google Chrome as well.  It's in version 9 (currently only on the dev channel, but soon on the beta channel, and a couple months away from everyone getting the update).  Use `window.webkitIndexedDB` to access it.

http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/LayoutTests/storage/indexeddb/tutorial.html is a tutorial that explains a lot of the current gotchas in the comments.

Hopefully we'll have something to post on the Chromium blog and/or html5rocks.com soon.