# Where is IndexedDB? And how do you use it?

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, web-standards

Wow! Web standards regarding databases seem to be a mess at the moment. Anyone care to help me codify the current state of IndexedDB because I can't for the life of me find a reasonable reference?

It seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949779/firefox-4-06b-indexeddb-support) post is no longer valid and the correct reference to the FireFox 4 IndexedDB is now `window.mozIndexedDB` .

As for Chrome and IE

NONE of the below examples seem to work for me and the objects they attempt to declare seem to not exist by testing using the browser development tools.

Specifically I refer to `window.webkitIndexedDB` in Chrome and `window.IndexedDB` in IE.

http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/ 
http://www.davidflanagan.com/2011/01/indexeddb-statu.html

PS: Im using Firefox 4, Chrome 10.0.648.204 and IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently IndexedDB is [only supported by Firefox](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb) and [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232382/indexeddb-can-i-start-coding-for-it-today/4292203#4292203).
You can consider using [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) that is supported in most of the modern browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately when attempting to mimic a relational database localstorage falls far short. Not least of all because of its 5mb storage limit.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately that's the state we are currently in. Hope it will change in the near future. In the meanwhile, using server-side storage should be the best approach.

Comment: IndexedDB is now supported by Chrome as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232382/indexeddb-can-i-start-coding-for-it-today/4292203#4292203